# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined Angular 6

Tags: javascript

Uncaught TypeError:

```
body = part.body.data;
body = atob(body.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/'));
```

When I used the following code it also give the same error.

```
body = part.body.data;
body = decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(content.replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/\_/g, '/'))));
```

It would be much appreciated if someone could shed some light on this!

Comment: what is output of ```console.log(part)``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be trying to perform replace on `undefine`.
That is the `body` variable is getting assigned with undefine returned by `part.body.data`.

Try either debugging this in your browser or do a
`console.log('printing --> part.body', part.body)`
to check its value.

Comment: logging `part.body` instead of `part.body.data` would be more useful (to see why `data` is not present) I guess